# Tafseer this ayah [2:30] "إِنِّي جَاعِلٌ فِي الْأَرْ ضِ خَلِيفَةً"

Tags: tafseer, adam-and-eve, surat-al-baqarah

The translation is:

> Remember, when your Lord said to the angels: "*I have to place a
>   trustee on the **earth*** <sup>`1`</sup>....." [2:30]

And these two ayah shows us how Adam and his wife lived in Janna, but after they made a mistake, God send them to Earth.

**[2:35]**

> And We said to Adam: "Both you and your spouse live in the **Garden**, eat
>   freely to your fill wherever you like, but approach not this tree or
>   you will become transgressors.<sup>`2`</sup>

**[2:36]**

> .... Go, one the antagonist of the other, and live on the **earth** for a time
>   ordained, and fend for yourselves."<sup>`3`</sup>

I heard the story like this:

Adam and his wife were living in Janna, they made a mistake for eating the tree because of Shaitan's temptation, Allah send them on the Earth.

But as we see, Allah told angles `I have to place a trustee on the Earth`, then Does Allah made his decision to put them on the Earth even before their mistake? OR **Does the word `Earth` in first ayah means `Garden` or `Janna` but in implicit way?**

---

`1, 2, 3`: From [**`tanzil.net`**](http://tanzil.net/#2:30), the translation of **`Ahmed Ali`**

Comment: I just want to add that prof Rafiq has comprehensively covered this topic in a lecture( in urdu )Quran and Insan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Aya (Al-A'raf [7:27]):

[image]

From http://quran.com/7/27

> O children of Adam, let not Satan tempt you as he removed your parents
>   from Paradise, stripping them of their clothing to show them their
>   private parts. Indeed, he sees you, he and his tribe, from where you
>   do not see them. Indeed, We have made the devils allies to those who
>   do not believe.

According to that aya, Allah only mentioned (parents) that removed from Paradise, therefore, we can conclude that Allah only placed our parents (Adam and hawa (lilith)) in Paradise but not us, then, it was clear from begging that Allah crated Children of Adam to live on earth...

Comment: +1, due to your answer, Adam and his wife were on earth then Allah told them live in Janna [(***`And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise....`***)](http://quran.com/2/35), it seems to be like a respect to Adam.
I am agree with you in that.

Answer (score 1):

When Allah (SWT) said in the Quran:

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority."

[Al-Baqarah 30](http://quran.com/2/30)

and in the same verse the angels replied:

> They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?"

[Al-Baqarah 30](http://quran.com/2/30)

According to tafsir `Ibn Kathir` and `Qurdubi`, the angels said this statement because allah has created the jinn before Adam and the jinn caused shed and killing on Earth.

This can be proven from the verse,

> And the jinn We created before from scorching fire.

[Al-Hijr 27.](http://quran.com/15/27)

However, `al-Qurdubi` added another interesting interpretation, Allah has already told the angels that this man(Adam) will cause corruption and shed blood because the word "خليفة"(khalifa) suggests or gives an impression to the angels that some of his children will not be as good as Adam since the word Khalifa means one who lead and have power to set justice on Earth.

But why would Allah create Adam ? Allah says in the Quran:

> And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.

[Ad-Dhariyat 56](http://quran.com/51/56)

As you can see he wanted the humans to worship him. So he let him enter the Jannah(Tafsir Ibb Kathir and Qurdubi say that the word Jannah means the Jannah) to test him. But he was misleaded by the satan so he was sent to Earth. and this is the wisdom of Allah. He promised Jannah(heaven) to those who will obey him and follow his orders. Those who will disobey will have severe punishment.

Comment: +1, however, I don't agree with: only jinn lived on Earth before Adam. Why I am thinking like that? From the ayah [2:30] `...sheds blood...`, Does jinn have a blood?

Comment: Jin were created from fire, and on the judgment day, some of them will enter Hell(which is fire) And they will be affected by it although they were created from fire. You see my point ? The jinn have their own world that we don't know much about. Hence they also shed blood for sure. but how ? allah knows best...

Comment: I am agree with `'Allah knows best'`, and about Jinn created from fire and will be punished by fire too, we are similar, humans are created from *clay*, me and you and all people around us, but when I *hit* you, you *feel* a pain, why? But we both created from clay.

Answer (score 1):

As we see, Allah told angles I have to place a trustee on the Earth, then Does Allah made his decision to put them on the Earth even before their mistake.
yes it means this earth. because you should a  faith that prophets do not commit error.it was the decision of ALLAH to send his khalifa on land so ADAM alaihi salaam was acting upon masihat e rabbani.That he knew he will commit this error and then ALLAH will send him on earth,because ALLAH has stated " have to place a trustee on the Earth" but placed him in jannah so it was WISDOM OF ALLAH. 
This is what heard from Islamic Scholars which also acceptable and sensible which gives the output that ALLAH is TRUTH and Speaks the Truth and Prophets are Innocent.

Comment: just one thing, we are not khalifa of allah, see tafsir of that aya and you will see that it has different meaning.

Comment: when i spoke of us,Khalifa means his Prophets alaihi salaams.Do let ur thinking be narrow make it wide,ISLAM is not so narrow.It is all About Love and Love has no limits

Answer (score 0):

It would seem quite possible that there were races / humans / peoples on the earth before Adam and his progeny, and that the Angels were referring to them:

al-Mas’oudi’ has a book entitled Akhbar al-Zaman. It has a chapter called “On the Peoples before Adam”.

I don't have the book but apparently it explains that there were 28 groups of peoples created on this earth before Adam, including a mankind that resembled the people of Adam. These groups mixed and interacted, leading to the expansion of the peoples to 120 groups.

Al-Maqdisi reportedly wrote about 3 pre-Adamic intelligent beings before Adam: two were Jinn, and the third flesh and blood. The 3rd group could be those referred to as “one who will make mischief therein and shed blood”.

here seems to be some mention of this topic in Tarikh at-Tabari-"تاريخ الرسل والملوك or Tarikh al-Rusul wa al-Muluk or Tarikh al-Tabari"

Previous ‘ulama have been discussing pre-Adamic and/or pre-human history for some time, and longer than the debate over evolution has existed.

I would love for anyone who has access to these books to fill me in, in English or Arabic.

[For detailed information - ‘Adams’ Before Adam?](http://saifulislam.com/2013/07/adams-before-adam/)