# Do we have any information in Islam about who were on Earth before Adam?

Tags: tafseer, creation, surat-al-baqarah

I didn't find any implicit Verse showing us who were on earth before Adam.

I think according to this verse [[**2:30**]](http://quran.com/2/30)

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed,
>   I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will
>   You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds ***blood***,
>   while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I
>   know that which you do not know."

Allah showing us(in explicit way) that there were  creatures living on earth that have **blood**.

Do we have any Hadith or another verse showing us who were living on earth before Adam?

Comment: Currently I don't have a reference at hand but AFAIK the Jinn were on Earth - they were created long before humans...

Comment: @Yahia: Yes, I know this, but I didn't mentioned that in the question because it will go to another subject: If Jinn were on earth before us, *`Does Jinn have blood`*, thats why I decided to not mention `Jinn`.

Comment: Whether they have blood I don't know but are several Ayat and Hadith that say for example that they can take part in intercourse between humans, that they can flow through a human being like blood...

Comment: About "sheds bloood" from the Aya you mention: I don't think that this is meant literally (although it could be) but it is definitely meant in a sense of "killing unjustly" and similar. Jinn are as all creatures not invivncible - they can kill and can die/be killed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the **Qur’an** or **sunnah** that indicate who lived on Earth before Adam. Rather the reports that speak of this are the opinions of those who wrote the Tafsir, among the companions and tabieen(Those who followed the companions).

To know what they have said go back to Tafsir At-Tabri, Ibn Kathir, and Tafsir "Tahreer and Tanweer".

In a nutshell, Either Jinn had lived before Adam or no one. Because as I said earlier in this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/9257/885) according to Qurdubi, the word Khalifa gave an impression to the angels that some of the humans will shed blood.

I would like to add a note from [Sheikh Abdulrehman Asa'adi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_ar-Rahman_ibn_Nasir_as-Sa%27di). He said in his Tafsir(Tayseer Ar-Rahman fy Tafsir kalam Al-Manan)(تيسير الرحمن في تفسير كلام المنان):

> We don't know who lived before us and we don't care because it won't contribute anything important(i.e increase our Iman or increase our level in Jannah)

Answer (score 2):

I have read about a book called 'Akhbar azZaman' written by al-Mas'oudi.  I read there was a chapter in it called "On the Peoples Before Adam".  There were apparently many peoples before Adam, including a people who resembled Bani Adam.

The same webpage mentions al-Maqdisi without giving the name of his book, and claims that it contains information of 2 types of jinn and one flesh-and-blood race that existed on earth before Adam.

Any of these, if they existed- Allahu A'lam-, could be whom the angels were referring to in the verse.

Importantly, pre-Adamic created races or humans could be the the identity of archaic humans used by evolutionists to support their theory.

I don't have access to any of these books.  If anyone does- English or Arabic- I would love to work out a way to see them, if only scanned copies of relevant pages.  Here's the website I found the information on:  [‘Adams’ Before Adam](http://saifulislam.com/2013/07/adams-before-adam/)

Comment: Your answer is very interesting. You made me research again to this subject. I was totally convince myself that there is noway to find out is there was other creatures before Adam or not. Thank you, I will try to get this books, I hope it's available.

Comment: asSalaamu 'alaykum.  You're welcome.  I think the subject is worthwhile because of what role these peoples might have played in Islamic or pre-Islamic revelations and history.